# Is there a usable iOS4 Terminal App?

Tags: ios, terminal

Mobile Terminal [426](http://code.google.com/p/mobileterminal/downloads/detail?name=Terminal-426-unstable.zip&can=2&q=) appears to be the only non-crashing iOS4 Terminal App. Unfortunately it's missing all of its convenience features, like gestures. Are there alternatives?

Comment: That's for jailbroken iOS isn't it?

Comment: Yes, forgot to mention.

Comment: From personal experience: Avoid pTerm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use iSSH: http://www.zinger-soft.com/iSSH_features.html
It's available on the app store, but if you're jailbroken you can ssh to 127.0.0.1 and it works just fine.  Costs $10 though.

Comment: Seems to be the best option available.

Answer (score 0):

If by terminal you mean SSH (or telnet): I have used TouchTerm (from way back when it was for free, now its 4$) and iSSH.

I like TouchTerm better on the iPhone as I find the semi-transparent keyboard better.

I prefer iSSH on the iPad because it has a real iPad version.

Also iSSH has a VNC client and an X server that can be tunneled over SSH. But its 10$.

Comment: iSSH has vnc? Really?

Comment: iSSH has VNC (and RDP) client capabilities (even tunneled over SSH): http://www.zinger-soft.com/iSSH_features.html